# Problem with differentiable function: is it concave up when the derivative is increasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

This makes sense to me, and I feel like it would be an easy argument IF I could use the second derivative.

I'm only given that f is differentiable, NOT twice differentiable. Any help?

Comment: What is your definition of concavity? This is really important information if you are constructing a proof.

Comment: If $f$ is concave up on $(a,b)$, then f is above all secant lines between any two points in $(a,b).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $f$ is below all secant lines?

Comment: @Spencer actually yes, you're right.

Comment: @Spencer I thought that because of a proof I previously did. guess I did it wrong (this one)

http://i.gyazo.com/f857c71af148851ed009743761a5d860.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Well, you're given that $f^\prime$ is increasing, implying that...

Comment: implying that.. what?

Comment: @terribleatmath In the sense of basic calculus, $f$ has a positive second derivative, and thus, that $f$ is concave up.

Comment: Sanath - can I make that argument? I was only given taht f is differentiable, not twice diffble.

Comment: @terribleatmath Well, if $f$ is not second-differentiable, then no comment could have been made in the first place about whether $f^\prime$ is increasing or not.

Comment: Is that really true? Surely you can have a nondifferentiable function that can be monotone increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @terribleatmath A function is concave up on an interval if it is continuous and its first derivative is continuous
and increasing on the interval. Use the fact that $f$ is differentiable, i.e., $C^\infty$ continuous.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that it being differentiable in this implication meant it was of class $C^\infty$. good to know.

that's an easy direction then. what about the other direction?

Comment: @terribleatmath If concave up, then the slope of slope is positive, i.e., $f^\prime$ is increasing.

Comment: what do you mean by "slope of slope" ?

Comment: @terribleatmath The tangent to the graph of $f^\prime$ has positive slope.

Comment: makes sense. is this due to the fact that the tangent lines of $f$ are all above $f$?

Comment: @terribleatmath If all tangent lines are above $f$, then $f$ would be concave down, as you can see from a graph.

Comment: hm, well all secant lines are above f, i thought it meant the tangent was too - can you explain why the tangents are below if the secants are above?

Comment: This isn't really true. The assumptions given do not imply the function is infinitely continuously differentiable. There are functions which are strictly increasing which are not differentiable everywhere. Strictly increasing only implies that $f(x+a) > f(x)$ for all $a > 0$.

Comment: As an example consider the piecewise defined function $f(x) =  x^2/2-1/6 $ on $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x)=x^3/3$ on $1 < x \leq 2$ which has a continuous increasing derivative everywhere on $[0,2]$ but whose second derivative is undefined at $x=1$.